Creating 'Event Deep Link' for in-app event
On App Store Connect, I want to create a In-App Event for a major update to my app. The in-app event form seems to ask for a "Event Deep Link", and I'm not sure how to quickly and simply do this. The preferred "Universal Link" seems to require some setup on the website, which I'd rather not do, and the "Custom URL" it wants seem unclear. I tried adding just the url scheme for my app in the field, but it considers it 'invalid'.
Since this is just to point out a 'major update' to the app, there isn't any special place I want to direct the users to ... I just want them to open the app! So what's the best way to fill in this field such that it opens my app?

how did you tackle this?

Just enter this link with your app id
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idYOUR_APP_ID

